$A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ iff $A\setminus C\subseteq B\setminus C$
I have attempted to prove the theorem, but I'm not sure whether I can invoke proof by contradiction on the converse the way I did or not.

$A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ iff $A\setminus C \subseteq B\setminus C$.
Proof.
$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$, and suppose $x \in A\setminus C$. Then it follows that $x \in B \cup C$, but since $x \notin C$, $x \in B$.
$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $A\setminus C \subseteq B\setminus C$, and suppose $x \in A \cup C$. Then either $x \in A$ or $x \in C$.
Case 1. $x \in A$. Suppose $x \notin B \cup C$. It follows that $x \in B\setminus C$. But the fact $x \in B$ contradicts with the fact $x \notin B$, so $x \in B \cup C$.
Case 2. $x \in C$. Suppose $x \notin B \cup C$. Then since the fact $x \notin C$ contradicts with the fact $x \in C$, $x \in B \cup C$.


If $x\notin B\cup C$, then $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$, so we can't conclude that $x\in B\setminus C$

@J.Chapman I used the fact $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$ along with the fact $A~\backslash~C \subseteq B~\backslash~C$ to infer that $x \in B~\backslash~C$.

I think I see what you were going for. My recommendation is to make your cases mutually exclusive. Case 1 and 2 might be satisfied at the same time. How about Case 1: $x\notin C$ (which then forces $x\in A$ but now you have more to work with), and Case 2: $x\in C$?

Your proof looks mostly good, though the only suggestion I have is that you may want to provide a brief justification as to how $x\in A$ and $x\notin B\cup C$ implies $x\in B\ \backslash\ C.$ The same could be said with the "Case $2$" proof.
For instance: Choose $x\in A$ such that $x\notin B\cup C.$ Then $x\in A\backslash(B\cup C)\subset A\backslash C.$ By using our assumption, we know that $x\in B\ \backslash\ C.$ But then $x\in B\cup C$ since $B\ \backslash\ C\subset B\cup C.$ With this contradiction, we may conclude that no such $x\in A$ can exist as an element not in $B\cup C.$
(So while you did invoke proof by contradiction correctly, your justification/utilization could use some additional steps.)

If I were to add the sentence such as ``It follows from $x \in A~\backslash~C$ and $A~\backslash~C \subseteq B~\backslash~C$ that $x \in B~\backslash~C$'' to the first case and a similar thing to the second case, then the proof would be more clear?

@Approxiz It would be more clear, but you would still need to justify how $x\in A\ \backslash\ C.$

I wonder about one thing. On Case 1, I have already stated that $x \in A$ before attempting to proof the case. When I invoked proof by contradiction to in saying that $x \notin B \cup C$, I infer that $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$. Isn't adding an additional step in saying that since $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$, $x \in A~\backslash~C$ redundant? I just want to make my proof as concise as possible, and adding such step when the fact which can be deduced from what have already been stated seems like a redundancy to me. Forgive me, I'm trying to make my proof as concise as possible.

@Approxiz What might be obvious to you may not be obvious to others. Yes, to somebody who already understands the implication without needing to be told, this may read as being redundant. However, to somebody who hadn't made the immediate connection, this detail could be the difference between a load of confusion and breezing through the proof. I hope this helps?

@JAG131 Please hava a look at my answer.

It is possible to use mechanicaly the correspondence between elementary set theory and propositional logic, $\cup,\cap,\subset...$ being replaced by $\lor, \land, \implies...$ resp.
The set property you want to establish is equivalent to prove that :
$$((a \lor c)\implies(b \lor c))\iff((a \land (\lnot c))\implies (b \land (\lnot c)))$$
is a tautology, meaning that the rightmost column of the truth table of this expression is filled with "True" values, which is indeed the case :
 a     | c     | b     | value | 
 --------------------------------
 False | False | False | True  | 
 False | False | True  | True  | 
 False | True  | False | True  | 
 False | True  | True  | True  | 
 True  | False | False | True  | 
 True  | False | True  | True  | 
 True  | True  | False | True  | 
 True  | True  | True  | True  | 

This truth table could be filled by hand, in a tedious way. Here, it has been built automatically by using  the symbolic logic library of SAGE (public domain software) ; I just typed these 4 lines :
 log = SymbolicLogic()
 s = log.statement("((a|c)->(b|c))<->((a&(!c))->(b&(!c)))")
 t = log.truthtable(s) 
 log.print_table(t)

Remark : please note that the columns are in the order $a,c,b$ because the compiler has met these letters for the first time in this order...=

Any comment ?...
